# Выбор региона сайта

Tags: jquery, php, wordpress

Здравствуйте. Есть сайт, где необходимо организовать выбор региона. В php я новичек, может будет глупый быдлокод, лучше поправьте. Как я делаю: 
сначала получаем регион, по которому кликнул юзер и выводим его в URL:

```
<div id="rega"><a href="#" title="Vitebsk">Витебск</a> <a href="#" title="Mogilev">Могилев</a></div>

$('#rega a').click(function() {
  var region = $(this).attr('title');
  window.location.href = 'http://wp/?region=' + region;
});
```

Потом получаем его название средствами PHP, сохраняем его в куки и делаем попытку отправить необработаный заголовок:

```
<?php
$defaultRegion = "Минск";

if(isset($_GET[region])) {
    $myRegion = $_GET[region];
    setcookie("region", $myRegion, time()+3600); //Устанавливаем куки на регион
    header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$myRegion); 
}
?>
```

Пишет

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...\header.php:5) in ...\header.php on line 28

Как добиться нужного функционала, чтобы юзер кликнул на ссылку, выбрался регион и он сохранился в куках и при последующем нахождении на сайте регион не изменялся?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В любом случае, заголовки надо посылать строго до любого вывода. В том числе, вывода пробельных символов, либо вывода ошибок.

В вашем случае попробуйте начать с проверки куков и гет-запроса. А уже потом выводить список городов/регионов

Comment: Так же, чтобы отправить заголовок нужно сначала получить то, что отправлять. В моем случае это $myRegion.
UPD: Пишет что заголовки уже отправлены в файле pluggable.php...

Comment: <?php
    if(isset($_GET[region])) {
      $myRegion = $_GET[region];
      setcookie("region", $myRegion, time()+3600); //Устанавливаем куки на регион
      header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$myRegion); 
    }
    //Все остальное

Answer (score 6):

1. Для начала, зачем вы делаете перенаправление (GET-запрос) средствами JS? Это можно сделать в самой ссылке:

   ```
   <a href="http://wp/?region=Vitebsk" title="Vitebsk">Витебск</a>
   ```
2. Во-вторых, если вы хотите эти манипуляции сделать без перезагрузки страницы, то добиться этого можно средствами ajax, отправляя данные в php-обработчик, в котором будут устанавливаться "печеньки"
3. И в-третьих, раз уж вы используете jQuery, то установить куки, можно достаточно просто -  используя плагин [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/)

Comment: 1) Мне же нужно было отдать регион выбраный пользователем php скрипту. Как я его могу отдать прямо из ссылки?

2) Можно и без этого.

3) А вот за это спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

1)

```
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/".$myRegion); // было myRegion
exit(); // это было пропущено
```

2) Раз уж это WordPress, то нужно использовать wp_redirect(), а не самодеятельничать.

Comment: Не знаю, попробывал wp_redirect() проблема осталась.
UPD: Пишет что заголовки уже отправлены в файле pluggable.php...

Comment: После wp_redirect() стоит exit() или die()? Если да, то значит, до этой точки есть какой-то вывод. Точнее - уже пошла загрузка темы, судя по header.php

Comment: стоит exit();

Comment: Ну тогда простой вопрос: в каком месте это происходит? Поскольку:
"Please note: wp_redirect will not be called if the page has started, so make sure to call it higher up.". Хорошее место для вызова проверки региона - хук на wp_init:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init (Runs after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent. Useful for intercepting $_GET or $_POST triggers.)

Answer (score 1):

У WordPress есть особенность. Он без нашего ведома может подключать служебные файлы. Поэтому лучше с куками и редиректом работать на JS.

Comment: Нужно читать кодекс и не заниматься самодеятельностью. Тогда и не будет казаться, что WP что-то делает "без ведома". Тем более что какие-то действия в обход API могут серьёзно поломать всю работу.